# Review \mu-almost proof

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to solve this excercise in Donald Cohns book, I think I should use diferently the \mu-almost part of the excercise but I would love a second opinion. I apologize for the rocky writing in advance, english is not my first language.

**The problem**

Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $f,g: X \to [-\infty, + \infty]$ be integrable and let $h: X \to [-\infty, + \infty]$ be an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function that satisfies $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ at $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$. Show that $h$ is integrable and that $\int h d\mu = \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu $.

**My attempt**

Let $h:X \to [-\infty, \infty]$ be a  $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Given that $f$ and $g$ are integrables, they are also simple ad an be written as:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\mathcal{X}_{A_i}(x) \qquad g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j\mathcal{X}_{B_j}(x)$$

Therefore:

$$\int f d\mu =\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \mu(A_i) \qquad \int g d\mu =\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j \mu( B_j)$$

Now, let $N \subseteq \mathscr{A}$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ be the subset that contains al $x \in X$ such that $h(x) \neq f(x) + g(x)$. Given that our integral definiton does not depend on the subsets or real numbers we use we can substitute each $A_i$ for $(A_i\cap N^c)$ and $B_j$ por $(B_j\cap N^c)$ so:

$$h(x)= f(x) + g(x) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\mathcal{X}_{(A_i\cap N^c)}(x) + \sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j\mathcal{X}_{(B_j\cap N^c)}(x) $$

Therefore $h$ is simple and its integral will be given as:

$$\int h d\mu =\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \mu((A_i\cap N^c)+ \sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j \mu((B_j\cap N^c)$$

and since we also have that $\mu(N)=0$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \mu((A_i\cap N^c)\cup (A_i \cap N)) + \sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j \mu((B_j\cap N^c) \cup (B_j \cap N))$$

$$=\int f d\mu =\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \mu(A_i) \qquad \int g d\mu =\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_j \mu( B_j)$$

$$= \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu $$

Comment: "Given that $f$ and $g$ are integrable, they are also simple..." - not true at all! They can be approximated by simple functions but need not be simple themselves.

Comment: Oh, would it be true if instead of a the sum of two sums I turnned it into one? I know that for it to be simple it has to have only a finite amount of values and since the $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s are those values I asummed it was enough

Comment: In general, an integrable function can assume infinitely many values. For example, $\sin(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure), but it is not a simple function.